# Finding unique elements in an array - compiler error

Tags: java

I am writing a method that will examine an array and return an array with only the unique integers, however I am getting a compiler error, "cannot find symbol, " at the return statement. How can I get around this?

The error:

Solution.java:35: error: cannot find symbol

symbol: variable finalUniqueArray

location: class Solution

```
  static int[] findUniqueElements(int[] a) {
    int[] uniqueArray = new int[a.length];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        boolean exists = false;
        int value = a[i];
        for ( int k = 0; k <= count; k++){
            if (value == uniqueArray[k]){
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        if (!exists){
            uniqueArray[count] = value;
            count++;
        }
        exists = false;
        }            
       int[] finalUniqueArray = new int[count];
        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
            finalUniqueArray[k] = uniqueArray[k];

        }
    return finalUniqueArray;
}
```

Comment: fix your indenting and you may find your error.

Comment: as @Hontaro said the variable is defined within the loop so it is not accessible outside the scope of the loop

Comment: Why don't you use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)  `return Arrays.copyOf (uniqueArray, count);`

Answer (score 2):

You declared `finalUniqueArray` in your for-Block, which means that it's a local variable and destroyed after the execution of the loop, therefore you can't access it in your return statement, which is outside of the for-loop

Answer (score 2):

You have used a local variable `finalUniqueArray` which was declared in a for loop.

```
// outer for loop's context
    int[] finalUniqueArray = new int[count];
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)    finalUniqueArray[k] = uniqueArray[k];

}
return finalUniqueArray;
```

If you are to access it outside the for loop, declare it outside the main for loop.

```
int[] finalUniqueArray=null;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    boolean exists = false;
    int value = a[i];
```

Then initialize it when you are going to use it,

```
finalUniqueArray = new int[count];
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++){
    finalUniqueArray[k] = uniqueArray[k];
}
```

Complete code:

```
static int[] findUniqueElements(int[] a) {
    int[] uniqueArray = new int[a.length];
    int count = 0;
    int[] finalUniqueArray=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        boolean exists = false;
        int value = a[i];
        for ( int k = 0; k <= count; k++){
            if (value == uniqueArray[k]){
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!exists){
                uniqueArray[count] = value;
                count++;
            }
            exists = false;
        }            
        finalUniqueArray = new int[count];
        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++){
            finalUniqueArray[k] = uniqueArray[k];
        }
    }
    return finalUniqueArray;
}
```